# There is only one real value of $a$ for which the quadratic equation has two positive integral solutions

Tags: roots, quadratics, integers, products

$$ax^{2} + (a+3)x + a - 3=0$$
This is the quadratic equation, and the question asks for product of roots.
(a) $9$
(b) $8$
(c) $6$

This is how I proceeded.
As far as I know if roots are integers then the Discriminant is going to be perfect square. 
So,
$D=(a+3)^2 - 4(a-3)a\qquad D+3(a - 3)^2= 36$

So, is there any way I can find the value of $a$.
Or this approach is totally wrong...
Thanks for help

Comment: "The discriminant is going to be a perfect square": this *could* be true, but quite not obvious, since there is not only the square root in the solutions formula, but also $a$ itself.

Comment: The roots of the equation is integral so the Discriminant has to be perfect square otherwise the roots would be irrational.isn't?

Comment: The roots not only contain $\sqrt D$ as a source of irrationality, but also $a$ which could compensate as we don't know whether $a$ is rational or not.

Comment: Oh! Yes thats is true .

Comment: What is the exact purpose of the exercise? Is it to find the value of $a$ given the value of the product of the roots?

Answer (score 3):

The coefficients/roots formula tells you that the product of the roots is going to be $\frac{a-3}{a}$. If this is an integer, say $n$, then $a=\frac{3}{1-n}$ is rational.

From there, your argument that $D$ has to be a perfect square is valid. However, it doesn't seem obvious how to list the values taken by a polynomial function that are perfect squares.

An easier way from here is to use the hint: $n\in\{9,8,6\}$. Therefore $a\in \{-\frac38, -\frac37, -\frac35\}$ and it boils down to hand checking.

---

Another approach is to use both coefficients/roots formulas:

$x_1+x_2=\frac{-a-3}{a}$ and $x_1x_2=\frac{a-3}{a}$ imply $$x_1x_2=x_1+x_2+2$$

This equation has a very limited number of solutions that are integers, since the left-hand side grows much faster than the right-hand side.

Comment: How do we get  ∈ {9,8,6}?

Comment: @Ceres It's in the initial question: *and the question asks for product of roots. (a) 9 (b) 8 (c) 6*